# Can't get titles to work with matplotlib in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm running through a tutorial of simple plot examples from the GeeksforGeeks website here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/using-matplotlib-with-jupyter-notebook/ The code I'm using is below:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [5, 2, 9, 4, 7]
y = [10, 5, 8, 4, 2]
plt.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
plt.title("GeeksForGeeks")
plt.xlabel("Time (hr)")
plt.ylabel("Position (Km)")
plt.show()
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

Everything works fine except that none of the plot labels, nor the title, are persistent. If I set the title, that works, but the data is missing from the plot. If I then set the x-axis label, then the title is gone, and the plotted data is still gone. If I plot the data again, the labels and the title are gone.

How can I get the plotted data, labels and the title to all be on the plot?

Also, the plt.scatter(x,y) code plots the data. Subsequent plt.show() plots nothing. That doesn't seem right. What can/should I do about this?

Thanks.

Comment: instead of using the `pyplot` interface, use the object oriented interface. basically, `plt.xlabel(...)` applies only to your first figure, not your second. but it's not even clear to the reader that you've created another figure, b/c of the stateful nature of the `pyplot` interface.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#the-object-oriented-interface-and-the-pyplot-interface

Comment: In Jupyter `plt.show()` pops up a new figure in most jupyter backends.  Don't call that until you are done adding all your labels.  I don't know why your tutorial does it any differently - probably they were not thinking you would be using a jupyter backend.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Each of the above code lines was in its own cell in Jupyter. Bringing them all into one cell, and running that cell, got everything working as expected.

I hope this info helps someone.